# simple html dom parser and pagination

Tags: html, parsing, dom

I use simple html dom parser to parse a website, and I have encountered a problem with handling the pagination on the website.
My actual code is to parse 1 page, and I'd like to parse all the pages:

```
<?php   

include ('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = file_get_html('http://www.ecran-portable.net/268-ecrans-pc-portable');

foreach($url->find('.product-name') as $produit)
echo $produit->plaintext . '<br />';

?>
```

Comment: Once you have parsed the page, you can also parse the pagination URLs and make a new request to those until no more pages left. You could store the already parsed pages inside a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand I have to do this, but I don't know how to achieve. Could you show me an example or some documentation where it was explained ?

Comment: Hi is There a way with a while or if ?